# Tomcat doesn't start with BIRT servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I don't have much experience with Java and I need a little help with the following issue.
I’m trying to make a Birt Java Servlet in order to generate PDF files based on a given input (XML in this case). I’m using Tomcat 7.0 for that I was able to create blank PDF files with this code (I’ve commented out a lot of lines in order to get Tomcat started).

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */

    public Servlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //get report name and launch the engine
        resp.setContentType( "application/pdf" ); 

        resp.setHeader ("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=test.pdf"); 



        String reportName = req.getParameter("ReportName");
        ServletContext sc = req.getSession().getServletContext();       
    }


    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }}
```

But when I try with the complete code that is:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    private IReportEngine birtReportEngine = null;
    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( "org.eclipse.birt" );

    public Servlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //get report name and launch the engine
        resp.setContentType( "application/pdf" ); 
        resp.setHeader ("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=test.pdf"); 



        String reportName = req.getParameter("ReportName");
        ServletContext sc = req.getSession().getServletContext();       
        this.birtReportEngine = BirtEngine.getBirtEngine(sc);


        IReportRunnable design;
        try
        {
            //Open report design
            design = birtReportEngine.openReportDesign( sc.getRealPath("/Reports")+"/"+reportName );
            //create task to run and render report
            IRunAndRenderTask task = birtReportEngine.createRunAndRenderTask( design );     

            task.getAppContext().put("BIRT_VIEWER_HTTPSERVLET_REQUEST", req );          

            PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
            options.setOutputFormat(HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);    
            options.setOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());



            task.setRenderOption(options);


            //run report
            task.run();
            task.close();
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException( e );
        }
    }


    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }}
```

the Tomcat Server (Version 7.0) doesn’t start anymore and the following info is logged to the console:

```
Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test_servlet]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test_servlet]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/IRenderOption
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:891)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5519)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRenderOption
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 20 more

    Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:694)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more

    Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:694)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 11 more

    Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 17, 2017 11:09:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Any help or example of a working Birt servlet would be apreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you building this?  Ultimately you don't have the BIRT libraries in your web application.  Normally they would live in the WEB-INF/lib directory within your webapp.

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks a lot for the response. I've managed to get the Tomcat running by including the jars. Now I'm receiving a NPE at the line that indicates the design file that is to be used and namely "   design = birtReportEngine.openReportDesign( sc.getRealPath("Reports")+"/"+reportName );". Any ideas?